# PHP Read array from file into array without quotes

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a function that writes a result from a db query into an array. Another function writes this array into a file.

Now I want a function that can put the contents of the file back into an array.

The array looks like this(both when i get it from the db and how it looks in the file):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0605
        [TIME] => 0605
        [1] => AGP
        [CODE] => AGP
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0610
        [TIME] => 0610
        [1] => NBE
        [CODE] => NBE
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0610
        [TIME] => 0610
        [1] => AYT
        [CODE] => AYT
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0620
        [TIME] => 0620
        [1] => TFS
        [CODE] => TFS
    )
)
```

i have tried this ->

```
public function file2Array($file){

    $filename = fopen($file,"r"); 
    $arr = array(); 

        while(!feof($filename)) 
        { 
    //read file line by line into a new array element 
    $arr[] = fgets($filename, 4096); 
    } 
    fclose ($filename); 
    return $arr;
    }
```

And it works but my array is returned with a (single)quote in front of every line(rendering the array useless ofcourse).

How would i return the array from the file into an array without quotes, exactly like in the file?

edit: Maybe i should mention that the file being read has .php extension

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to search the problem with the file writing function first? (Btw, there's something else for reading in files line-wise: [`file`](http://php.net/file).)

Comment: My initial reaction is to ask why you're storing a data type -- an array -- in a file. I think it'd be much easier, especailly with the simplicity of this array, to store the array into a CSV file with headers, and that would make it much easier to extract the values as their real data types.

Comment: So the database connection only has to happen 1 time a day.The file will be created with the daily data and used instead of connecting the db. A csv is fine 2.

Comment: @sjoerd As mentioned the file contains the (exact same) array as posted above

Comment: I just tried your code.. I didn't get any leading single quotes.. Please post the file contents.. thanks! Oh and.. opening a .php file should be okay.. it's not processing the file as a script but just as a file..

Comment: also, how about use json to serialize the array and store it to a file instead? You can encode and decode pretty easily.

Comment: Mat I have solved it thanks to your suggestion. I can't post the answer yet but I will once I can.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said - use some data format. CSV, JSON, XML - anything will do.

What you are doing now is just writing output of print_r or var_dump (or whatever function you use) to a file. Output of those functions are for informational purposes, NOT for storing data.

Here are some quick functions for you:

```
function array_to_file(array $array, $filename)
{
 $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
 foreach ($array as $a) {
     $string = json_encode($a).PHP_EOL;
     fwrite($handle, $string);
   } 
   fclose($handle)
}

function file_to_array($filename)
{
   $result = array();
   $array_of_lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
   foreach ($array_of_lines as $line){
     $result[] = json_decode($line, true);
   }
   return $result;
}
```